# How to send SMS Texts and iMessages from PHP mail() without knowing the Carrier

Tags: email, sms, phpmailer, imessage, carrier

In earlier years, when I wanted to programmatically send text messages to mobile phones/cell phones I needed to know the carrier and the carrier's text service domain name in order to form the To: address.

But these days, many sites are able to text without asking me for my carrier.

How are they doing that? Is there a new way to send sms and imessage "emails" without the carrier element?

Comment: PHPMailer knows nothing about SMS, but some mobile networks have email to SMS gateways. Otherwise I suggest using an SMS gateway directly, such as Clickatell.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Synchro. So if I interpret your comment, your answer is that you (still) cannot send mail messages without knowing the carrier's mailing domain. Otherwise, you need to use a third party API (either free or paid-for). Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You might be able to find a list since there are not that many carriers

Answer (score 0):

However they are doing it, they are ultimately sending a message to a correctly formatted 'email' address.  For example, if a person has mobile phone number 555-666-7777 and the carrier is AT&T.. they are sending a message to 5556667777@txt.att.net.

They could be using a service that takes a phone number and returns a properly formatted 'email' address, or they could be using a script that tries each carriers 'postfix' after a given number until they find one that works.  There is also the possibility for any phone number that it doesn't belong to a device that can accept email messages (an SMS is ultimately an email message) such as a landline.